# blur a portion of colormap

Tags: matlab, plot, colorbar

Starting from this code and figure:

```
clc
clear all

[x, y, z] = peaks(1000);

figure;
p = surf(x,y,z);
shading flat

cm=colormap;

Xm=-7;
XM=8;
caxis([Xm XM])

colorbar
```

[image: from]

I can highlight the values in a certain range `[Xm XM]` by modifying the colormap. For example by setting the color in that range to red:

```
[x, y, z] = peaks(1000);

figure;
p = surf(x,y,z);
shading flat

cm=colormap;

Xm=-7;
XM=8;
caxis([Xm XM])

x1=2;
x2=4;
l1=findnearest(x1,linspace(Xm,XM,length(cm)));
l2=findnearest(x2,linspace(Xm,XM,length(cm)));

cm(l1:l2,:)=repmat([1 0 0],l2-l1+1,1);

colormap(cm)
colorbar
```

[image: to]

Is there a way to make the transition less abrupt? Maybe by blurring the color near the transitions?

**Edit:**

The code makes use of the [findnearest](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2838-findnearest-m) function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the colors in between aren't important, you can use some simple linear fading:

```
n = floor((l2-l1+1)/2);
fade = linspace(0, 1, n)';
cm(l1+n,:) = [1 0 0];
cm(l1:l1+n-1,:)=fade * [1 0 0] + (1-fade) * cm(l1-1, :);
cm(l2:-1:l2-n+1,:)=fade * [1 0 0] + (1-fade) * cm(l2+1, :);
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: If you want even smoother transitions, you can upsample your colormap first before any calculations (i.e. before computing `l1` and `l2`) like so: `cm = parula(256); colormap(cm);`